# Veterinarian immigrant years income in Canada

Tags: canada, working, canadian-citizens

I want know what is the average veterinarian migrant annual income in Canada?

I have seen this [post](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/salary-how-much-do-vets-make-125652) about average incomes of veterinarians in Canada like this:

> The Bureau of Labor Statistics (BLS) reports that veterinarians earn a
>   median salary of $88,770. The best-paid veterinarians earn $161,070,
>   while the lowest-paid earned $52,470. Vets in their first year of
>   practice can expect to earn a salary of approximately $60,000.

So based on [this post](https://neuvoo.ca/salary/?job=indian), the average incomes of migrants in Canada is:

> The average Indian salary in Canada is $34,125 per year or $17.50 per
>   hour. Entry level positions start at $25,350 per year while most
>   experienced workers make up to $49,725 per year.

But my cousin is a veterinarian and says this income is not for migrants veterinarian in Canada. There is a ceiling income for them of $18000 one year before becoming a citizen (maybe after a 5 year period of waiting to become a citizen, even passing the veterans exams).

Comment: The salary numbers you've quoted are for people with the word "indian" in their job title, eg. "Indian Cuisine Cook". That has nothing to do with their ethnicity. Many immigrants from South Asia work as Software Developers, look those up then you'll see what they can make. Their is no ceiling for the income of immigrants in Canada. It's fortunately a free country and you can negotiate your salary with your potential employeur or better still - start your own business.

Comment: Possibly a minimum income level, as opposed to a ceiling?

Comment: @Traveller, yes my cuousin said, the ceiling incone for migrsnts is below minimum incomes for canada  citizen veterinarians, and this is the main question, is this happened in reality?

Answer (score 1):

The post that supposedly shows salaries of immigrants is nonsense. It shows salaries for jobs with "Indian" in the job title. Like a school looking for a "teacher of Indian languages", or a university looking for an "Expert in Indian History", or an Indian restaurant looking for a "Chef cooking Indian food". You don't have to be Indian for these jobs, and Indians are not restricted to these jobs. So the number you got there is totally pointless.

As a veterinarian, you (most likely) cannot just start a job in Canada, but you need qualifications. If you are a qualified veterinarian in India, you need to check whether your qualifications are accepted in Canada or not. Then you need to check whether your experience is valid in Canada (the expected ways to treat various animals might be different). Then you need to check out the job market in Canada: Are there lots of open jobs for veterinarians or not?

So if you have the qualifications, based on inexperience in Canada, language problems, you can probably look at the lower end for veterinarians in their first year. Then you work your way up, get higher paid jobs, possibly open your own practice, and there is no reason you can't get to the upper limit.

There is definitely no upper limit for the income you are allowed to make in Canada. If your cousin finds someone willing to pay him a million dollars per year (he won't), he's free to make that money. There may be *lower limits* where you can't bring someone else into the country unless you have some minimum income yourself, and there $18,000 sounds quite reasonable.